# Git subtree fails to push to Heroku

Tags: django, git, heroku

I tried to push my Django app to Heroku

```
git subtree push --prefix TEST heroku master
```

It gives me something like this

```
'TEST' does not exist; use 'git subtree add'
```

If I use git subtree add, it gives me

```
Working tree has modifications.  Cannot add.
```

I am not sure what is the problem and how to fix it. Has Anyone encountered the same problem before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite clear.

```
Working tree has modifications.  Cannot add.
```

The branch where you are working on has modifications. Commit them.

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'Commit to add a subtree (or whatever)'
```

*Then*, use `git subtree add`.

Comment: Now I get this. fatal: couldn't find remote ref master

Comment: Is it because I did something wrong in intermediate steps?

Comment: git subtree add --prefix TEST heroku master

Comment: if I use git push heroku master, I run into errors as well.

Comment: [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/myurl'

Comment: Try using `main` instead of `master`, that might work.